# Can I put Plotlegend to each my rho values?

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to put `PlotLegend[]` into my graph for every `rho` value. Graph `P` is for `Purple` and `M` is `Magenta`. 
Every pair of `P` and `M` there is `rho` value.

I want my Legend to display `rho=0.0` the graph is `Dotted`and `rho=-0.01` the graph is `Dashed` for every pair of my `Purple` and `Magenta` graph.There is 5 values of `rho`. Is it possible?

```
Tmp = 0.1316;
P[T_, α_, β_, ρ_] = 
  Sqrt[(α^2 β - T α^2 β + T α^2 β ρ - Tmp α^2 β ρ)/(α^2 β - ρ^2)];
M[T_, α_, β_, ρ_] = 
  Sqrt[(T α^2 β + Tmp α^2 β - (ρ (α^2 β - T α^2 β + T α^2 β ρ - 
    Tmp α^2 β ρ))/(α^2 β - ρ^2))/(α^2 β)];

Manipulate[
 Plot[{
     Table[M[T, α, β, ρ], {ρ, {0.0, -0.01, -0.05, -0.1, -0.5}}],
     Table[P[T, α, β, ρ], {ρ, {0.0, -0.01, -0.05, -0.1, -0.5}}]
   },
   {T, 0, 2},
   AxesLabel -> {"T", "M/P"},
   PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, y}},
   PlotLabel -> "M/P againts temperature",
   ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotStyle -> {Magenta, Purple}
 ],
 {α, {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2}},
 {β, {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2}},
 {{x, 1}, 0.01, 2, 0.01},
 {{y, 1}, 0.01, 2, 0.01}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just removed capital variables. I have interpreted the aim as having distinct 'labeling' for functions `m` and `p` (red, purple) and for values of `rho`. In this example dashing is used.

```
tmp = 0.1316;
p[T_, α_, β_, ρ_]:=
  Sqrt[(α^2 β - T α^2 β+t α^2 β ρ -tmp α^2 β ρ)/(α^2 β - ρ^2)];
m[T_, α_, β_, ρ_]:=
  Sqrt[(t α^2 β+tmp α^2 β-(ρ (α^2 β-t α^2 β + t α^2 β ρ-tmp α^2 β ρ))/
   (α^2 β - ρ^2))/(α^2 β)];
```

then

```
rng = {0.5, 1, 1.5, 2};
rho = {0.0, -0.01, -0.05, -0.1, -0.5};
leg = Join @@ ({Row[{"M: ", #}], Row[{"P: ", #}]} & /@ rho);
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Join @@ Table[{m[t, α, β, ρ], 
      p[t, α, β, ρ]}, {ρ, rho}]], {t, 0, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"T", "M/P"}, PlotRange -> {{0, x}, {0, y}}, 
  PlotStyle -> 
   Join @@ Table[{{Red, Dashing[{j, j}]}, {Purple, 
       Dashing[{j, j}]}}, {j, 0, 0.08, 0.02}], 
  PlotLabel -> "M/P againts temperature", ImageSize -> Large, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   LineLegend[Automatic, leg, LegendLabel -> "ρ"]], {α, 
  rng}, {β, rng}, {{x, 1}, 0.01, 2, 0.01}, {{y, 1}, 0.01, 2, 
  0.01}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @ubpdqn for your help is really appreciated. now i can continue my project

Comment: @Nabil thank you. I am glad it was helpful. :)